# Azure CDN (verizon premium) angular app getting 404 with URL having

Tags: angular, regex, azure, cdn

We are hosting our angular app on Azure CDN (verizon premium) and rewrite works well except when the URL looks like this: `https://example.com/main/getuser/user.name` Then i'm getting 404.
[image]
If the URL is `https://example.com/main/getuser/username` everything is fine.  I understand that the problem is the dot `.` but can't figure out the right regex.
I have 2 rewrite rules:
`/123456/path/((?:[^\?]*/)?)($|\?.*)` -> `/123456/path/angular-files/index.html$2`
`/123456/path/((?:[^\?]*/)?[^\?/.]+)($|\?.*)` -> `/123456/path/angular-files/index.html$2`

[image: rewrites]

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#fallback-routes

Comment: I don't see how will that help

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution :

- For the Pattern, Use `[^?.]*(\?.*)?$.` This pattern catches URL paths with `.` in them, but doesn't care whether or not it's in the query string.
- For the source Path, enter `origin_path/document.ext`.The Path is relative to the origin root. For example, if your CDN endpoint's origin path is `/origin_path` and you want to redirect to `index.html`, you would enter `origin_path/index.html`. This will always be the case if your CDN is backed by an Azure Storage Account and the origin points to a container.
- The Destination pattern will be the origin path which is set in your Azure portal settings + index.html. So if your origin path is `"/cdn"` then in the Destination pattern you would write, `"cdn/index.html"`
- Click Add to add your rule and wait some time, it should resolve the issue.

**Note:** Please add a public access to blobs and containers for azure storage account, otherwise CDN will error out blob not found.

**Reference:**

[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49401118/azure-cdn-with-verizon-rewriting-url-to-always-load-index-html)